# Python3, Pandas: Update DataFrame in both directions, with priority

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Apologize if this is a RTFM question, but numerous docs and questions all seem to solve slightly different problems than this: How can I most elegantly update an existing DataFrame with a newer, partly overlapping? 
That is; both-dimension merge with specified priority.

```
>>> old_df   #  Original data frame which I would like to update
            Stat1  Stat2
Time
2020-04-17  117.2  217.2
2020-04-18  118.2  218.2
2020-04-19  119.2  219.2

>>> new_df   #  More recent data frame, partly overlapping the original in both dimensions
            Stat1  Stat3
Time
2020-04-18  118.1  318.1
2020-04-19  119.1  319.1
2020-04-20  120.1  320.1
2020-04-21  121.1  321.1

>>> upd_df   #  Desired result; new where possible, old otherwise
            Stat1  Stat2  Stat3
Time
2020-04-17  117.2  217.2    NaN
2020-04-18  118.1  218.2  318.1
2020-04-19  119.1  219.2  319.1
2020-04-20  120.1    NaN  320.1
2020-04-21  121.1    NaN  321.1
```

At the time of coding; the shapes, column names and time periods of the two DFs are not known.

Code to create the two DFs and the desired result:

```
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> old_ttags =  [pd.Timestamp('2020-04-17'), pd.Timestamp('2020-04-18'), pd.Timestamp('2020-04-19')]
>>> old_data = {'Time': old_ttags, 'Stat1': [117.2, 118.2, 119.2], 'Stat2': [217.2, 218.2, 219.2]}
>>> old_df = pd.DataFrame(old_data).set_index('Time')

>>> new_ttags =  [pd.Timestamp('2020-04-18'), pd.Timestamp('2020-04-19'), pd.Timestamp('2020-04-20'), pd.Timestamp('2020-04-21')]
>>> new_data = {'Time': new_ttags, 'Stat1': [118.1, 119.1, 120.1, 121.1], 'Stat3': [318.1, 319.1, 320.1, 321.1]}
>>> new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data).set_index('Time')

>>> upd_ttags = [pd.Timestamp('2020-04-17'), pd.Timestamp('2020-04-18'), pd.Timestamp('2020-04-19'), pd.Timestamp('2020-04-20'), pd.Timestamp('2020-04-21')]
>>> upd_data = {'Time': upd_ttags, 'Stat1': [117.2, 118.1, 119.1, 120.1, 121.1], 'Stat2': [217.2, 218.2, 219.2, np.nan, np.nan], 'Stat3': [np.nan, 318.1, 319.1, 320.1, 321.1]}
>>> upd_df = pd.DataFrame(upd_data).set_index('Time')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `combine_first`:

```
new_df.combine_first(old_df)
```

Output:

```
            Stat1  Stat2  Stat3
Time                           
2020-04-17  117.2  217.2    NaN
2020-04-18  118.1  218.2  318.1
2020-04-19  119.1  219.2  319.1
2020-04-20  120.1    NaN  320.1
2020-04-21  121.1    NaN  321.1
```

Comment: Ouch, that easy!  Thanks a lot :-)